# What impact Azure Service Plans can have on Sitecore environment setup?

Tags: paas

Recently i learnt how to setup Sitecore 9.0 on Azure PaaS. I want to understand how Azure App Service plans could impact setting up Sitecore environments:

1. If we have to setup Dev, QA, Preprod/UAT and Prod on Azure PaaS, do we need to repeat the Sitecore setup steps once for each environment, steps corresponding to chosen Azure topology (XM, XP scaled etc.)?
2. What I understand is that as per Azure App Service plan (standard, premium etc.) it limits the number of instances. For standard it’s 10 instance max, premium 20 max, do we have to take that into consideration when planning how many environments we can have on Azure?
3. If we are on standard service plan will we be able to deploy Sitecore XP, as it may need more that 10 instances for the resources (CM, CD, Processing, Reporting etc) that have to be provisioned by it?
4. Also how do we deal with Data Recovery setup for Prod, is that a part of the Azure offering. Or it need to be planned separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but if you are using ARM templates, you can just change a couple of parameters and rerun them to create your additional environments. It is good practice for having your QA environment to reflect your production. But ultimatly, that's up to you.
2. The number of outscaling instances is one of the differences between basic, standard and premium. But there are many more differences like ssl support. The power of Paas is that you can easily up/down and in/out scale at any time. So, your initial setup does not need to be your final one.
3. Note that the hosting cost is on the App Service Plan, and an app service plan can contain multiple apps. I don't now the amount of traffic you need to process, but 10 servers is a lot. On a PV2, you can go up to 20 instances. And if that is not enough, you can setup multiple CD farms and put a traffic manager in front of it. We are running a S3 with 5 instances to handle 20K request/min during peak traffic.
4. Yup, it is part of Azure. Database point-in-time restore is by default enabled, but has a limit of a good month. However you can setup longterm backups as well. For the app services, you can also enable backups via azure.